# how to add dynamic image in crystal report with out using database in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio

1. Insert a default image
2. Right-click on the default image to view its properties.
3. Go to the Picture tab.
4. There is a formula editor for Graphic Location. Put the formula for your filepath & name there.

bt in visual studio 2008 cant show the formula in picture tab.

Comment: I'm not really seeing an actual question here?

Comment: this is task done it visual studio 2010   
-1
down vote
favorite
Insert a default image Right-click on the default image to view its properties. Go to the Picture tab. There is a formula editor for Graphic Location. Put the formula for your filepath & name there bt i wanna do that thing studio 2008 .because in picture tab no option for formula

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried setting filepath through a formula, but how I typically solve this is:

- create a `List<byte[]>`
- read in all the images in code, convert them to byte arrays and put them in the list
- set the list as the report's `DataSource`
- in Crystal Reports designer, drag & drop the byte[] field from *Field Explorer* to the report's *Details* section

Unfortunately the designer just shows an empty rectangle, but when running the reports these rectangles should be rendered as images!

Comment: dear i know that thing bt wanna do that thing via that mode.if any idea about that plz tell me

Comment: sorry, cant help you in that regard since I've never done it that way and have no 2008 version here to try it out...